# ¿Cómo implementar en un único script awk varias expresiones awk?

Tags: script, awk

En un archivo **personal.csv** tengo la siguiente información:

```
Center_code       Name                 City_code    Men    Women
    800      SCHOOL NUMBER ONE            8000      28      31
    801      SCHOOL NUMBER TWO            8010      33      9
    802      INSTITUTE GALCERAN PINE      8020      16      22
    803      EASD PINE                    8030      43      17
    804      SCHOOL NUMBER THREE          8040      14      5 
    805      INSTITUTE CAN CLOS           8050      6       18
    806      ESCRBC CAT                   8060      5       6
    807      SCHOOL NUMBER FOUR           8070      9       8
    808      EASD TOWER                   8080      5       11 
    ...       ...........                 ....     ...     ...
```

Tengo el siguiente comando awk para calcular la suma de los valores de una columna de un archivo csv:

```
awk '{SUM+=$4}END{print SUM}' file2
```

Con el siguiente comando calculo la media de la columna:

```
awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{s=s+$4;}END{print s/NR;}' file2
```

Y con este último comando calculo la desviación estándar de la misma columna:

```
awk '{sum+=$4; sumsq+=$4*$4} END {print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)^2)}' file2
```

Necesito implementar las tres anteriores expresiones en un único script **awk** (en un archivo usando el **shebang `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`**, no usando una línea de comandos), guardando cada resultado en una variable distinta.

La salida debería ser del siguiente tipo (los valores son inventados):

```
MEN
Total men = 134(24%) --- Average men = 2,978 --- Standar deviation men = 2,266

WOMEN
Total women = 421(75%) --- Average women = 9,356 --- Standar deviation women = 7,874
```

Los cálculos deben hacerse con aquellas filas del archivo personal.csv que contengan un tipo de colegio que debe pasarse al script. Por ejemplo, si le pasamos como colegio **EASD**, solo debería hacer los cálculos con las filas siguientes:

```
803      EASD PINE            8030      43      17
808      EASD TOWER           8080      5       11
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi propuesta se enfoca tanto a la presentación del código como a la presentación de los datos. Si bien fedorqui contestó haciendo énfasis al problema del dueño de la publicación sobre poner múltiples sentencias de `awk`, en lo que yo me centro es en la presentación.

Estos ejemplos los muestro suponiendo que el archivo de donde se obtiene es, literalmente, uno `csv` con el primer renglón como su *header*, por ejemplo.

```
Center_code,Name,City_code,Men,Women
800,SCHOOL NUMBER ONE,8000,28,31
801,SCHOOL NUMBER TWO,8010,33,9
802,INSTITUTE GALCERAN PINE,8020,16,22
```

El código es:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

NR == 1 {
    #  Obtenemos el header tanto de los
    #+ hombres como de las mujeres en caso
    #+ de que sea el primer renglón.
    h_header = tolower($4)
    m_header = tolower($5)
    next #  Después de obtenerlos, nos 
         #+ saltamos ese renglón.
}

{
    h_suma += $4
    h_sumsq += $4^2

    m_suma += $5
    m_sumsq += $5^2
}

END{

    N=(NR - 1) # Porque el primer renglón es el header

    #[START] Operaciones de hombres.
    h_percent = h_suma * 100 / (h_suma + m_suma)
    h_media = h_suma/N
    h_desviacion_std = sqrt(h_sumsq/N - h_media^2)

    print toupper(h_header) # Ponemos el título de encabezado.
    printf "Total %s = %s (%s %) --- ", h_header, h_suma, h_percent
    printf "Average %s = %s --- ", h_header, h_media
    printf "Standard deviation %s = %s \n\n", h_header, h_desviacion_std
    #[END] Operaciones de hombres.

    #[START] Operaciones de mujeres.
    m_percent = m_suma * 100 / (h_suma + m_suma)
    m_media = m_suma/N
    m_desviacion_std = sqrt(m_sumsq/N - m_media^2)

    print toupper(m_header) # Ponemos el título de encabezado.
    printf "Total %s = %s (%s %) --- ", m_header, m_suma, m_percent
    printf "Average %s = %s --- ", m_header, m_media
    printf "Standard deviation %s = %s \n\n", m_header, m_desviacion_std
    #[END] Operaciones de mujeres.

}
```

La forma de correr el código (digamos que le pusimos de nombre `calculos.awk`) es:

```
awk --field-separator="," --file=./calculos.awk datos.csv
```

O (por los comentarios):

```
awk -F "," -f calculos.awk datos.csv
```

Y la salida es muy parecida a la deseada:

```
$ awk --field-separator="," --file=./calculos.awk datos.csv
MEN
Total men = 154 (57.037 %) --- Average men = 19.25 --- Standard deviation men = 12.9976

WOMEN
Total women = 116 (42.963 %) --- Average women = 14.5 --- Standard deviation women = 8.52936
```

#### Hay otra opción.

`datamash` es una herramienta que apenas conocí desde hace un año que puede darte gran parte de lo que deseas.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ datamash --field-separator="," -H  sum 4 mean 4 pstdev 4 sum 5 mean 5 pstdev 5 < datos.csv | column -t -s ,
```

Resultando en algo por el estilo:

```
sum(Men)  mean(Men)  pstdev(Men)      sum(Women)  mean(Women)  pstdev(Women)
154       19.25      12.997595931556  116         14.5         8.529361054616
```

Comment: He ejecutado el script, pero no me da resultados. He ejecutado usando el siguiente comando: awk -f script.awk -v center="EASD" personal.csv > extracted.txt (con el EASD extraigo las filas del csv que me interesan) Pero el output me sale así: Total = 0 (-nan %) --- Average = 0 --- Standard deviation = 0 ¿Sabes a qué puede deberse? Mi archivo csv está separado por comas, pero no sé cómo pasar esto con la ejecución del script (quizás no imprima resultados debido a que no se indica cuál es el separador del csv en el propio script awk).

Comment: @sergei, justamente acabas de dar una respuesta a tu pregunta. ¿Ya probaste si con el parametro `-F ","` o `--field-separator=","` te funciona?
Por cierto, sería de utilidad que pusieras un pequeño fragmento de tu archivo `personal.csv` en tu publicación.

Comment: lo suyo @sergei es que consigas datos con formato más estándar (los que salen en la pregunta no lo tienen demasiado)

Comment: Si utilizo el comando que tu me indicas `awk --field-separator="," --file=./script.awk personal.csv` me sale este mensaje de error: `awk: not an option: --field-separator=,`. Si utilizo el otro comando `awk -f script.awk -v center="EASD" personal.csv > extracted.txt` no sé cómo pasar el separador del csv. Tu comando habría que adaptarlo para que extraiga del fichero `personal.csv` aquellas filas que contienen la palabra que se pasa (que sería en el ejemplo `EASD`).

Comment: @sergei usa `awk -F ',' -f script.awk`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ahora me sale la presentación, pero los estadísticos los calcula en base a todo el fichero `personal.csv`, no los calcula utilizando solamente la parte del fichero cuyas filas contienen la palabra que se pasa (en el ejemplo `EASD`).

Comment: @sergei Eso no lo pusiste en tu publicación por lo que ninguna respuesta lo toma en cuenta. actualiza tu publicación para que se te pueda ayudar o realiza otra publicación con esa duda en concreto, una vez hayas trabajado con tu ejemplo y te surjan otras dudas específicas.

Comment: @Cuauhtli perdón, no lo había aclarado. He actualizado la publicación.

Comment: Estoy con Cuauhtli en que @sergei sería mejor que publicaras otra pregunta, pues tu actualización está invalidando las respuestas existentes. Es por eso que hay que presentar siempre un [mcve] porque si no nos pasamos el tiempo actualizando y reactualizando respuestas

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' perdón de nuevo. Publico otra pregunta. Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: @sergei Si consideras que una de las siguientes preguntas resolvió tus primeras dudas, es necesario que marques como la respuesta valida. Lo digo también porque que vi el código, que escribí para ayudarte, intacto en una nueva pregunta tuya.

Comment: @Cuauhtli en la otra pregunta he puesto lo que se me olvidó poner en esta.

Answer (score 5):

Juntar los comandos consiste en simplemente agruparlos:

```
awk '{sum+=$8; sumsq+=$8*$8}
     END{
         print sum;
         print sum/NR;
         print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)^2)
     }' file2
```

En una sola línea:

```
awk '{sum+=$8;sumsq+=$8*$8} END{print sum; print sum/NR; print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)^2)}' file2
```

Nótese que no es necesario definir el valor inicial de las sumas: cuando se usan por primera vez ya se inicializan.

Para tenerlo en un script, pégalo allí :)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{sum+=$8; sumsq+=$8*$8}

END{
     print sum;
     print sum/NR;
     print sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)^2)
}
```

Guárdalo como archivo.awk y luego ejecuta con `awk -f archivo.awk fichero`.

Si quieres "tunear" el resultado puedes hacer `printf "el resultado es: %f\n", sum` y cosas así.

Comment: No sería exactamente juntarlos. Es decir, tengo que escribir un script con el shebang #!/usr/bin/awk -f cada una de las expresiones, y guardar el resultado en una variable para cada una de ellas.

Comment: Vale, si eso la parte de preguntar, etc la hacemos en la otra pregunta [Cómo extraer filas de un csv que cumplan una condición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/350311/83). Aquí dejamos la lógica de las tres operaciones

Comment: edité mi respuesta para que se vea cómo ejecutarlo como script separado

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo guardar cada resultado en una variable, para poderlos presentar con la salida que indico al principio? Es decir, cada valor numérico sería cada una de las variables correspondientes.

Comment: en `END` puedes decir `END {var1=sum; var2=sum/NR}`, si bien no le veo utilidad pues lo que haces es imprimir el resultado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Me olvidé una pequeña cosa. Para tener una salida de los datos como la que indico al principio de la pregunta, ¿se haría dentro del END?

Comment: Se cogerá todo lo que imprimas. Por ejemplo si haces `awk 'BEGIN {print 23}'` y luego dices `res=$(awk 'BEGIN {print 23}')` entonces la variable "$res" de la shell valdrá 23.