# Cómo extraer filas de un csv que cumplan una condición

Tags: shell-script, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo que implementar en un script awk (en un archivo que contiene el shebang `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`, no usando una línea de comando) lo siguiente: primero de todo, hay que preguntar al usuario que introduzca el valor de un tipo de colegio, que puede ser AFA, CEE, CFA y EASD. El valor que introduzca se debe almacenar en la variable **center**. A partir de este valor hay que extraer las filas de un archivo file1 cuya columna 2 contenga el valor de esta variable, y guardar todas estas filas en el archivo file2. Por ejemplo:

```
awk '/SCHOOL/ { print }' file1
```

El archivo file1 contiene la siguiente información:

```
Center_code       Name                    City_code
   800      SCHOOL NUMBER ONE               8000
   801      SCHOOL NUMBER TWO               8010
   802      INSTITUTE GALCERAN PINE         8020
   803      EASD PINE                       8030
   804      SCHOOL NUMBER THREE             8040
   805      INSTITUTE CAN CLOS              8050
   806      ESCRBC CAT                      8060
   807      SCHOOL NUMBER FOUR              8070
```

Si el usuario introduce el valor **SCHOOL**, se deben coger las filas que contienen en la columna **Name** el valor **SCHOOL**, y guardar todas estas filas en otro archivo diferente.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: la lectura de respuestas por parte del usuario se puede hacer con Awk, pero realmente será salir de Awk para entrar en la shell y preguntárselo. Me extraña pues que se plantee así, sería mejor hacer un simple `read` y luego pasárselo al script de Awk. Por otra parte, sería bueno que mostraras lo que has hecho hasta ahora, para ver dónde necesitas más ayuda

Comment: Me piden leer el valor del tipo de colegio dentro del script de awk. Con este valor extraigo las filas correspondientes, las guardo en un archivo, y este archivo es el que utilizo para calcular el total, la media y la desviación estándar. Del script no tenía nada hecho hasta ahora, solo tenía el planteamiento. Soy novato en este tema, y ando aún muy verde.

Comment: me resulta muy extraño que se quiera hacer esto con Awk. Lo lógico sería un script en Bash que pidiera estos datos y que luego ejecutara el script de Awk de [tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/350306/83), para finalmente leer los resultados en Bash y escribir los valores

Comment: ¿Pero podría hacerse todo dentro del mismo script de Awk?

Comment: Se puede hacer, pero básicamente implica "salir" de Awk y ejecutar un comando externo para luego recogerlo. Me parece raro que se os pida algo así de complicado y poco útil si estáis empezando con Bash y Awk

Comment: ¿Podría hacerse una llamada al script desde la línea de comandos, pasándole como parámetro el tipo de colegio y que ya en el script se realice la búsqueda de las filas?

Comment: Sí, eso sí. Si llamas al script con por ejemplo `awk -f archivo.awk -v parametro1=valor1 parametro2=valor2 fichero`, entonces desde dentro del fichero puedes usar la variable `parametro1`, `parametro2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un script determinado y llámalo con:

```
awk -f archivo.awk -v center="valor" fichero
```

Dentro de `archivo.awk` referencias la variable `center` y haces algo así como:

```
awk '$2 == center' fichero  # el 2.º campo es exactamente igual
                            # al contenindo de center
```

o bien

```
awk '$2 ~ center' fichero  # el 2.º campo contiene
                           # el contenindo de center
```

Si es un script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$2 == center
# o bien $2 ~ center
```

---

Veamos un ejemplo completo:

```
$ cat fichero
1 hola
2 hola 
3 adios
4 adeu
```

El sccript:

```
$ cat script.awk 
$2 == center
```

Ejecutamos:

```
$ awk -f script.awk -v center="hola" fichero
1 hola
2 hola
```

Para guardar en otro archivo, redirigimos con `comando > fichero_destino`:

```
awk -f script.awk -v center="hola" fichero > fichero2
```

Comment: A adaptar según delimitador de columnas. Habría que ver si debe _contener_ o no. Si es "contiene" sería `$2 ~center`, tal y como expliqué en https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384347/1983854

Comment: En mi caso tendría que ser "contiene", ya que los nombres de los colegios están formados por varias palabras. Entonces, si no he entendido mal, habría que hacer esto: $ awk -v center="hola" '$0~center' file  Y dentro del script se hace referencia a la variable center así: $2 == center  ¿Sería así?

Comment: Disculpa, tuve que dejar el ordenador y dejé a medias. Lo que cambiaría sería el script, que pasaría a ser `$2 ~ center`. La asignación con -v center="bla"` se mantiene igual

Comment: Una última cosa. Si en el script quiero imprimir el valor de la variable center, ¿se imprimirá el valor que he introducido al pasar el parámetro al script, en este ejemplo, bla?

Comment: @sergei sí, estará disponible la variable para escribirla, modificar o hacer lo que quieras con ella

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: edité la respuesta con todo lo comentado por aquí en los comentarios